# Install Visual Studio 2002 on Windows 7 or Vista

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-7, windows-vista, visual-studio-2002

I want to install Visual Studio 2002 on Window 7(32bit). When I try it gives me error of .NET Framework 1.0 incompatibility. I can install Framework 1.1. fine on the machine but VS 2002 needs 1.0.

**Note:**

I am aware of VS 2002 and Framework 1.0 are incompatible on Windows 7 / Vista but
I have it installed on another similar machine and have been using it for a while. Unfortunately, I don't remember what I did to make it work then.

Any suggestions, workaround, ideas or solutions are really appreciated.

1. Please don't tell me it is incompatible and/or downvote because I am 100% sure I have it running on one machine.
2. Also I HAVE to use VS2002 due to legacy application.

Comment: Why would you need 2002? 2010 is out right now.

Comment: I was able to install VB6 onto my Win7 x64 bit machine using [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).  Perhaps you can do the same?

Comment: @Blender: Have to use it with legacy app.

Comment: @Smudge202: I think it is .NET 1.0 issue and VB6 doesn't require .NET.

Comment: You should use a virtual machine with Windows XP. That's likely what the developers were using originally with VS2002.

Comment: @Ed Chapel: What's bugging me is why it is running on one machine and not another. This machine had XP Pro and upgraded to Win7 and so instead of VM, I will move it back to XP if I can't make this work.

Comment: Thats how to install .NET 2003 on Vista, I am sure the process for 2002 won't be much different:

http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2007/03/09/how-to-setup-asp-net-v1-1-visual-studio-net-2003-projects-on-iis7-vista.aspx

Comment: @Sean: I have been to that link. I am able to install Framework 1.1 but VS 2002 needs Framework 1.0. Actually that's the main issue I think. I also have IIS 6 Compatability Mode set.

Comment: Try turning off DEP and manually installing .NET Framework 1.0 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/02/04/error-installing-net-framework-1-0-and-1-1-on-windows-vista-caused-by-data-execution-prevention-dep.aspx

Comment: You can also temporarily disable the Application Experience service, which should stop the incompatible messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With several tries I was finally was able to install VS2002 on Win7.
Uninstalled all other frameworks(2.0+) which were installed as part of VS2005 / SQL Server 2008 installation. 
Also found something that the Windows installer might have got corrupted and did something to repair that and some other registry settings.

Main difference I can recall is that on this system I had other frameworks, MVC, etc. before installing VS2002 and that might be causing some conflict.

But again I can't say what exactly solved the problem. So may be I should have started from scratch with plain OS only.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install VS 2002 in Windows 7 x86.

1. Uninstall all newer frameworks.
2. Install VS 2002 by un-selecting "Visual Studio Analyzer" and "Application Center Test"